# NFC tag with user authentication

Tags: nfc

The goal is to have an NFC tag that will give a certain information, remain unlocked, and would only allow an authenticated user(login/pass) to change that data? Is that possible?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. Your question is, strictly speaking, perhaps not programming related. But NFC-related questions seem to tend to blur the line between software and hardware, so I still think this is the right place to pose the question.

NFC tags can contain different chips with different capabilities, depending on the manufacturer.  When you look at NFC Forum Type Tags, there are the following options:

1. Type 1 Tag: Offers possibility to lock the data, but does not support authentication, AFAICT. Original manufacturer was Innovision Research & Technology PLC, now owned by Broadcom.
2. Type 2 Tag: Offers possibility to lock the data. There are various manufacturers. Some chips offer also authentication and write protection, for example MIFARE Ultralight C.
3. Type 3 Tag: Based on Sony FeliCa technology, main (only?) manufacturer is Sony. FeliCa chips offer authentication features and write protection. FeliCa systems are mainly used in Eastern Asia.
4. Type 4 Tag: Based on ISO 14443-4 and ISO 7816-4 specifications. Offers possibility to indicate write protection. The chips that support this are generally micro-controller cards, which often offer advanced features such as authentication, encryption and write protection, for example the MIFARE DESFire family of chips.

Other commonly supported NFC tags:

1. MIFARE Classic: Offers access control, including write protection. Can also support NDEF message storage.
2. ISO 15693 based: Some chips offer (limited) authentication functionality and write protection, for example ICODE SLIX-S (can also support NDEF message storage).

Then there is the family of JavaCard cards (often Global Platform compliant) and other ISO 7816-4 supporting cards. These usually offer very advanced features such as a file system and custom programs, including support for authentication, encryption, digital signature, etc. They usually require special tooling and training to be able to work with them.

I would recommend looking at MIFARE Classic and, if that does not meet your security requirements, MIFARE DESFire.

Comment: How to make NFC Tag lock with my app and unlock the same with my app. any working example there? please can refer me on

Comment: Just in case someone reads this answer in 2017 or later: MIFARE classic is no longer a secure option: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIFARE#Security_of_MIFARE_Classic.2C_MIFARE_DESFire_and_MIFARE_Ultralight